# Apache POI: Exception while calculating formulae

Tags: java, apache-poi, illegalargumentexception

I have gone through many questions posted here and referred POI documentation too, but i am not able to resolve this issue.

Issue: When trying to re-calculate the formula i am getting an exception.

Formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("#DFLT=",COUNTIF(C5:C390,"=DEFAULTERS"),"; #NP=",COUNTIF(C5:C390,"=NOT PAID"),"; #PCsh=",COUNTIF(C5:C390,"=Paid Cash"),"; #PChk=",COUNTIF(C5:C390,"=Paid Cheque"),"; #PNeft=",COUNTIF(C5:C390,"=Paid Neft"))
```

Exception:

```
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected eval class (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.MissingArgEval)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.coerceValueToString(OperandResolver.java:275)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.TextFunction.evaluateStringArg(TextFunction.java:40)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.TextFunction$8.evaluate(TextFunction.java:249)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:132)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:525)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:288)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:51)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getValue(AreaEvalBase.java:109)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.CountUtils.countMatchingCellsInArea(CountUtils.java:55)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Countif.countMatchingCellsInArea(Countif.java:452)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Countif.evaluate(Countif.java:441)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:132)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:525)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:288)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:230)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:354)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluate(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:185)
10-22 17:13:15.177: E/AndroidRuntime(26300):    at com.android.impressico.readupdateexcelfile.ExcelFileWriter.writeCellToFile(ExcelFileWriter.java:121)
```

I made following attempts to re-calculate formula:

1. // ExcelFile.workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
2. // HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(ExcelFile.workbook);
3. for (Row r : sheet) {
   for (Cell c : r) {
                           if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                               System.out.println("Evaluating formula for cell = " + c.getCellFormula());
                               evaluator.setDebugEvaluationOutputForNextEval(true);
                               evaluator.evaluate(c);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After enabling the poi logs i found that the cell on which

```
=CONCATENATE("#DFLT=",COUNTIF(C5:C390,"=DEFAULTERS"),"; #NP=",COUNTIF(C5:C390,"=NOT PAID"),"; #PCsh=",COUNTIF(C5:C390,"=Paid Cash"),"; #PChk=",COUNTIF(C5:C390,"=Paid Cheque"),"; #PNeft=",COUNTIF(C5:C390,"=Paid Neft"))
```

was dependent, were also excel formula.

```
=CONCATENATE(" {",HZ5," - ",IA5,"}, ","{",IB5,,"}")
```

This formula had an extra comma(,), Which was causing an MissingArgument while parsing the formula, and while evaluating this Missing Argument results in IllegalArgumentException.

POI logs showed:

```
10-30 16:56:18.377: I/System.out(26511): [POI.FormulaEval]I       * ptg 7: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.MissingArgPtg [ ]
10-30 16:56:18.377: I/System.out(26511): [POI.FormulaEval]I         = org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.MissingArgEval@42be7f58
```

Answer (score 2):

POI can now *evaluate* formulas which apply the range operator to area refs.

However, POI still cannot *parse* these formulas. For example, these calls will fail:

```
cell.setCellFormula("AVERAGE(J6:OFFSET(I6,0,DAY(TODAY())-1))");
cell.setCellFormula("SUM((C1:D2):(D2:E3))");
```

Refer this [link](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=762250) to fix for the same

Comment: I have to evaluate formula only, setting of formula is done in excel only. My aim is to only re-compute the value. Could you please elaborate, why this exception is occurring, So that i can give a try to handle is properly.