# Apache poi Formula evaluation error

Tags: java, apache, excel-formula, apache-poi

when I execute the code below I can print "odd" value but I am unable to print "netodd" value. Both are numeric value types and Formula for odd is =K3*K4/100 and for netodd is =K9-K10-K11

```
FormulaEvaluator ev = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator()   

        XSSFCell odd = sh.getRow(8).getCell(10);
        ev.evaluateFormulaCell(odd);    
        System.out.println(odd);

        XSSFCell netodd = sh.getRow(11).getCell(10);
         ev.evaluateFormulaCell(netodd);
        System.out.println(netodd);
```

Actually I found that 
"INDEX(C700001:C748210,MATCH(F14&C6,."INDEX(C700001:C748210,MATCH(F14&C6,A700001:A748210&B700001:B748210,0))" ,0))" this formula results in error Can someone help me out how to evaluate this formula using poi. 
The error displayed in console log is

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected eval type (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval)"

Comment: Probably need to check the validity of the formula in the second cell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache POI: Exception while calculating formulae](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517141/apache-poi-exception-while-calculating-formulae)

Comment: I tried above link but it is displaying the same error. My K9 cell is odd cell, netodd cell depends on odd cell(which is a formula cell).

Comment: What are the formulas for all the other involved cells?

Comment: IF condition, MATCH & INDEX, VLOOKUP.

Comment: One of them is malformed

Comment: Actually I deleted those formulae and tried with just numeric values, Still it is displaying the same error. I think error with " =K9-K10-K11" this formula.

Comment: Actually I found that this formula results in error."INDEX(C700001:C748210,MATCH(F14&C6,A700001:A748210&B700001:B748210,0))" Unable to evaluate this formula using poi.